# Twitter api user profile information in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter

Could anybody tell me how to get a user ' s complete details in twitter api after fetching access_token.
 In twitter blog i found in a question that
        "You can then issue a request to the canonical source of information about a user, GET users/show with a request like GET https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=kool_aid_wino -- this response will include fields pointing to the user's current avatar image and so on."

I dont understanding correctly [Users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show) how to use it..??

Is there any tutorials or examples of asp.net you know to accomplist this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example regarding Http web request you will get an idea..

http://stritar.net/Post/Using-JSON-with-asp-net-is-like-wiping-your-ass-with-silk.aspx